# After running windows 7 on dual boot system (with Ubuntu 14.04), machine does not reach GRUB

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub

I did the following:

1. Partitioned my C drive
2. Installed Ubuntu 14.04 from USB .iso
3. After my computer failed to boot, I used the [boot repair disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), live from USB, to fix. This fixed the issue.
4. I started Ubuntu and shutdown
5. I started Windows7 and shutdown

After doing this, the machine no longer reaches GRUB. It just endlessly restarts in a loop.

What is the best way to go about debugging this? Is there a way to prevent windows interfering with the boot system?

Answer (score 1):

Start ubuntu from live cd, install [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) e check what happened

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu (or other OS) after installing Windows, Windows should not change the boot record.

However if Windows thinks that the master boot record has problems and attempts a fix, it will destroy your boot settings, and you have to use the Ubuntu Live USB to boot in and manually fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks - yes this seems to described what's happening. Any idea how to stop it attempting a fix?

Comment: Better make sure that it isn't a UEFI/GPT Windows installation first.